# How to successfully save a high resolution image from Python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, fractals

I've been experimenting with drawing fractals on Python, and I'm finding the PDF file format to be insufficient for what I want to do. I am using matplotlib pyplot to generate and save these images.

Originally, I thought that a PDF would have been sufficient to see all the detail that my program had actually calculated. Instead, however, at a certain scale, the result from my output PDF becomes jagged and looks like this:

[image: The PDF, zoomed in to a fine scale.]

When I use a PDF, there doesn't seem to be anything I can do in my program to avoid it becoming jagged. No matter how finely or otherwise I actually compute the fractal, it becomes jagged always at the same scale.

When I use a JPEG at, say, 1500dpi, I do not get this problem. Instead, I get a result like this:

[image: The JPEG, zoomed in to around the same scale.]

However, the issue is that I can't really produce a JPEG at a resolution greater than around 4000dpi or my program just stops, and my computer struggled to open the images if they are successfully saved.

Is there a way to improve the quality of the PDFs I am generating, or perhaps some other file format I can try?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not really clear. What exactly is undesired about the first image compared to the second? What's the  [mcve] to show that problem?

Comment: I think the problem lies more in your expectations. You do not share your code, but my guess is *the jagged display is actually correct*. Sure, if you use a bitmap output you don't get the jagged edges. But that's not something that got *changed*; the algorithm is the same, but making it a bitmap adds an amount of simplification and rounding.